# Turn-Based Multiplayer Quick Start

Tags: java, android, google-play

[The Google guide for Turn-based Multiplayer Support in Android Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#selecting_players_with_the_default_user_interface) walks through how to start a new match using the default UI using `getSelectedOpponentsIntent()`. It also mentions the following:

> Alternatively, you can implement a Quick Start button to let users bypass the player picker UI, and instead use some default criteria to build the match.

I'm having trouble finding any examples on how to accomplish this. To my understanding, I would need to manually create the Intent that `getSelectedOpponentsIntent()` creates if you add an Auto-Match partner.